Is there a theory in which all types can be omitted?
Is there a natural example of a first order complete (consistent) theory $T$ in which every 1-type can be omitted? or is there always some isolated type? In that case, why?
Of course there are plenty of limitations of such a theory: the language can have no constants, it can not be $\omega$-categorical, etc... I can't think of a reason why $S_1$ must have isolated points, but I can't think of an example of such a theory $T$.
I know that, in the continuous theory of atomless probability algebras with one generic automorphism, all types can be omitted but the types of the two constants, corresponding with the empty event and the universe. But I would like an example when no type is isolated, and if possible in (discrete) first order logic.
I would also prefer "natural" examples, if there is any. Something that is also studied in some other branch of maths.

In the language with infinitely many unary predicates $U_i$ ($i\in\mathbb{N}$), for $\sigma$ a finite binary string let $\varphi_\sigma$ be the sentence saying that there is at least one element $x$ such that $U_i(x)$ holds whenever $\sigma(i)=1$ and $\neg U_i(x)$ holds whenever $\sigma(i)=0$. Models of this theory correspond to dense subsets of the Cantor set (possibly with "duplicate points"), types over this theory correspond to points in the Cantor set, and there are no isolated complete 1-types.
